# How to make 5V 650 mA on a summer camp?

Tags: battery-charging, generator, charging

On our summer scouts camp, I need to power a tablet (it simulates the computer from The Lost, and the children must activate it every 108 minutes). It requires 4.3 - 5.3 V and about 650 mA. I need to power it for 6 days, but the problem is, there is no electric outlet or something nearby. So basically we must make the electricity or use batteries. And for it to be harder, the financial limit for this project is 18 EUR (20 USD), which isn't a lot obviously. I would also like to note that we have a 1000W electric generator, but it can run for only about 2-3 hours/day.

So I came up with two solutions how to power the tablet:

**Solution 1: Use batteries**

I can buy and use a bunch of batteries. Problems:

1. Capacity - I need 15,6 Ah/day, which is a lot for batteries and
   this financial limit.
2. Charging - I can use the electric generator, but can I charge a battery in 2 hours?

**Solution 2: Generate electricity ad-hoc**

I have a dynamo from old Czech car, which (according to the internet) can output 12V 55A (is it possible?) and maybe connect it to a stationary bike, and children will have to use the bike to charge 18650 lithium batteries, which will then power the tablet.

**I like the second option more. What do you think? Do you have more solutions? Any advice appreciated. Or feel free to ask for more details. Is it even possible?**

Notes:

- My level of knowledge of electronics is low-medium, but I don't have much practical experience.
- I made a practical test. 4 AA NiMH 2300 mAh batteries charged the tablet for 8 hours. Those numbers don't make sense, theoretically it should have been 15 hours!

Comment: This is an excellently-asked question. (I'm editing out the comment about your English, because it's perfectly fine. :) )

Comment: Does the tablet have to be on for the entire time? It should be fine keeping the timer running with the screen off, and that will dramatically reduce your power consumption. Also, have you actually measured the power consumption? If that number is from the adapter, it's possible it's the worst-case draw, and the idle-with-screen-on is much lower.

Comment: I can believe that the dynamo is capable of 55A, but not when pedal-powered. You should still be able to get a usable current from it though (2A would be a generous amount for charging).

Comment: The tablet must be on, because when I put it into sleep, it also pauses the timer. Yes, I have soldered a special USB "interuption", which is connected to multimeter and which measures voltage and current. When the battery is fully charged, it draws 650 mA @ 5V, when it is depleted, it draws about 950 mAh. (It was very cheap tablet, around 40 USD, and it is about 2 years old)

Comment: The original adapter is certified for 2A @ 5V, but since I switched off WiFi and turned the brightness down, I get only 650 mA.

Comment: The dynamo connected to the bike sounds like a fun project, but the voltage output will vary with the speed and the power output will be proportional to the speed times the applied torque.  An adult cyclist can easily put out sustained power of 100-200W, some can put out peaks of 400W or more.  The problem is you will need some electronics to convert the variable output of the dynamo to something you can use to charge a reservoir battery (or the devices directly) and I don't think you can get there for 18 Euros.

Comment: I'd use a flywheel between the bike and the dynamo, but that will definitely be out of your budget.

Comment: Well, the dynamo outputs 12V, but I need 5V. I will be using a voltage regulator (like 78S05) to convert 12VDC to 5VDC. And this should get rid of the problems with the variable output, or not? Also, I have got an old laptop battery. Inside I have found 3 18650. Can I use those as "buffer"?

Comment: You want a buck-boost convertor, not a linear regulator. The batteries will help to an extent, but then you'd need two convertors and a charger.

Comment: The dynamo is rated for 12V around whatever idle speed the original engine ran at. (800 RPM or so?).  A cyclist generally spins at something around 90-100 RPM so you can't necessarily count on the dynamo putting out 12V.  Also, a linear regulator isn't very efficient even if you had the 12V.  At 1A it would be dissipating 7 watts which would require a large heat sink.  A buck-boost converter would be more appropriate but maybe out of your price range.

Comment: Well buck-boost converters are a little bit out of budget, but can I ask, what is the practical difference between buck-boost converter and linear regulator? I have read about them on wiki, but the only difference I have found so far is efficiency.

Comment: A buck/boost converter can give you a constant voltage from a variable input voltage. A linear regulator must start with a voltage higher than the output voltage by some amount (generally at least 1V).

Comment: @EricGunnerson is correct, a buck boost can output a constant voltage with an input voltage either above OR below the output voltage. The linear regulator must have an input voltage somewhat above the output voltage to work.

Comment: This seems ridiculous. Program a background service for the timer. It should run even if the tablet is asleep. That's how every clock app works.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, how long must the computer be on?  You mention that it must be activated every 108 minutes, and I assume this means it must be turned on every 108 minutes.  Then for how long does it get turned on for?  At a rate of 650 mA, if it is only on for say 1/2 hour every 108 minutes the you would only use 325 mA every 108 minutes.

Assuming you follow the 108 minutes 24 hours a day, then you would turn on the tablet 13 times for 1/2 hour in a 24 hour period.  You are camping for 6 days so a total of 13 x 6 = 78 - 1/2 hour sessions (or however long you are turning it on for).

At 650 mA, 78 - 1/2 hour sessions (650 mA x 78 x 1/2) = 25.35 amps

Your Nimh are at 1.2 volts, so put 4 in series to get 4.8 volts (closer to 5.6 volts fully charged so be careful).  When in series, the capacity is NOT added, so have only 2300 mAh capacity with the 4 in series.

25.35/2.300 = 11.02

So you would need 11 sets of batteries, or recharge them 11 times if you use the tablet for 1/2 hour every 108 minutes 24 hours a day for 6 days straight.  I have a feeling that you won't be using the tablet this much, so you will have to adjust your calculations accordingly.

I know that you mentioned 18650 batteries, but given you budget and your options, I think that a good quality Nimh is your best choice. The main reason is because you can get a reasonably priced Nimh AA battery that can be charged in less than 2 hours!  Many lithium ion batteries will take longer to safely charge.  Plus the voltage of 4 Nimh batteries matches what you need.  Get a fast charger that will charge 4 at once.  You can get chargers that will charge Nimh in as little as 15 minutes, but that is hard on the batteries.  I would go for a 1 hour charger with the generator.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. However, the problem is, that when I developed the app, I didn´t know that it has to be energy saving, so I developed it in Game Maker Studio, which (I believe) doesn´t support background tasks on Android. And it is better for children to see the countdown. So ideally, the screen would be on for six days. Well about that 18650, I have found some in old laptop battery pack - the laptop was about 10 years old. Do you think they are useable? Thanks.

Comment: @user72028 - I have salvaged hundreds of 18650 from old laptops and sometimes the batteries are in great shape, sometimes they are dead.  I'm my experience,  any laptop battery older than 5 or 6 years is likely to be dead.  Lithium ion die from old age as often as they die from too many cycles.   Re do your tests to see if you can get the tablet to use less than 650mA by turning off wifi etc.  Try testing Nimh again and maybe you need 3 or 4 sets of them.  The other problem with lithium ion besides higher cost for you is that their voltage doesn't work with what you need where 4 Nimh should.